# a simple markov chain model for treatment

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose doctors are experimenting with two treatments without knowing which one is better.
Call treatments $A$ and $B$. One is likely better, but we don’t know which one. A series of patients will each be given one of the treatments. We aim to find a strategy that ensures that as many as possible of the patients are given the better treatment — though we don’t know which one this is.

Given that for any patient, $\mathbb P( \text{ treatment A is success})=\alpha$ and
$\mathbb P( \text{ treatment B is success})=\beta$, $0<\alpha, \beta<1$.

For any patient, doctors can choose with equal probability which treatment to go ahead with. Let $P_R$ be the overall probability of success for each patient. so $P_R=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta)$.

There is another strategy where for the first patient doctor chooses treatment $A$ and $B$ with equal probability at random; if the $n^{th}$ patient is given treatment $A$ and it is successful, they use the treatment $A$ for the $(n+1)^{th}$ patient too.

A similar rule is patient $n$ is given treatment $B$, and if it is successful, they use the treatment $B$ for the $(n+1)^{th}$ patient too. If not, switch to treatment $A$ for the    $(n+1)^{th}$ patient.

So, the treatment system can be expressed with a Markov chain with $4$ states, right?

$\{A_s, A_f, B_s, B_f \}$

Could anyone tell me how if I have written the correct transition probabilities?

$\mathbb P( X_{n+1}=A_s \mid X_n=A_s)=\frac{1}{2}\alpha$

$\mathbb P( X_{n+1}=A_s \mid X_n=B_f)=\frac{1}{4}\alpha(1-\beta)$

$\mathbb P( X_{n+1}=A_s \mid X_n=B_s)=0$

$\mathbb P( X_{n+1}=B_s \mid X_n=B_s)=\frac{1}{2}\beta$

$\mathbb P( X_{n+1}=B_s \mid X_n=A_f)=\frac{1}{4}(1-\alpha)\beta$

$\mathbb P( X_{n+1}=B_s \mid X_n=A_s)=0$

Where $A_s$ means that the patient was given treatment $A$ and was successful. $f$ indicates failure.

Define $P_T$ to be the long-run probability of success in this strategy.

Could anyone tell me how to find the equilibrium distribution $\pi$ for the process? Find $P_T$, the long-run probability of success for each patient in this strategy.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Inaccuracies in the transitions**

I don't think your transition probabilities are correct.

For instance, condition on $X_n = A_s$, $X_{n+1} \in \{A_s, A_f\}$, but you haven't defined a probability for $\mathbf P[X_{n+1} = A_f | X_n = A_s]$.

Further, still conditioning on $X_n = A_s$ the respective probabilities are simply the probability $A$ succeeds/fails, so:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf P[X_{n+1} = A_s | X_n = A_s] & = \alpha,\\
\mathbf P[X_{n+1} = A_f | X_n = A_s] & = 1-\alpha.
\end{align*}$$
So we don't need the factor $\frac12$ you have in your first formula.

**Complete Transition Matrix**

Let $P$ denote the transition matrix, and I'll assume the order of the four states that you provided $\{A_s, A_f,B_s, B_f\}$, then thinking through each scenario, as above, you can show:

$$P = \left(
\begin{matrix}
\alpha & 1-\alpha & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \beta & 1-\beta \\
 0 & 0 & \beta & 1-\beta\\
 \alpha & 1-\alpha & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
 \right)$$

**Calculating the stationary distribution**
This is an irreducible, aperiodic, Markov chain on a finite state space, so it is guaranteed to have a unique stationary distribution, $\pi$ (e.g. Theorem 4.9 in [Levin and Peres](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf)).

Further, by definition of a stationary distribution, it satisfies:

$$\pi P = \pi.$$

Applying this to the matrix above, we have the system of equations

$$
\begin{align*}
\alpha(\pi_1 + \pi_4) = \pi_1 \\
(1-\alpha)(\pi_1 + \pi_4) = \pi_2 \\
\beta(\pi_2 + \pi_3) = \pi_3 \\
(1-\beta)(\pi_2 + \pi_3) = \pi_4
\end{align*}
$$

Combining the first two equations, we find that $\pi_2 = \pi_4$, which we'll denote $p$. Then respectively substituting $p$ for $\pi_4$ for $\pi_2$ in the second and fourth equations we find:

$$
\begin{align*}
\pi_1 = \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}p \\
\pi_3 = \frac{\beta}{1-\beta}p
\end{align*}
$$

Since $\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 + \pi_4 =1$ we have:

$$1 =\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}p + p + \frac{\beta}{1-\beta}p + p,$$

Equivalently:

$$p = \frac{1}{2 + \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} + \frac{\beta}{1-\beta}}.$$

So we have the stationary distribution:

$$
\pi = 
\frac{1}{2 + \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} + \frac{\beta}{1-\beta}}
\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} \\
1 \\
\frac{\beta}{1-\beta} \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

**Success Probability**

Having run the Markov chain long enough, (approximately) any patient can expect to be in each state according to the stationary distribution $\pi$. Successful patients are those in states $A_s,\, B_s$, which correspond to $\pi_1,\pi_3$.

So the probability of success in this strategy is

$$ \pi_1 + \pi_3 = \frac{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} + \frac{\beta}{1-\beta}}{2 + \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} + \frac{\beta}{1-\beta}}=\frac{\alpha+\beta-2\alpha\beta}{2-\alpha-\beta}$$

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the value of $P_T$ in my question in your answer? Thank you for your time

Comment: I've added a final section explaining this.

Comment: $\pi$ will be a row vector rather a column vector right?